# Restart Apache2 in Windows XP with PHP

Tags: php, apache

I have a PHP file that when executed must restart Apache. I tried as follows:
I put in the last line:

```
exec('C:\apache2restart.bat');
```

And the file. Bat

```
net stop apache2 && net start apache2
```

But it's just stopping Apache, it does not restart. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I'm assuming the PHP process is getting killed during that batch command, since the webserver just shut down. This seems a very, very bad idea though...

Comment: @slugonamission The PHP process just launches another process, which should not be killed with it. I think... And it depends on how the php file is called. PHP can be called from the command line in which case Apache has nothing to do with it.

Comment: The .bat is somehow tied to PHP which is terminated with APACHE, there is no parameter in exec () or another function that creates the process originated independently?

Comment: Not if it's a server plugin. Also, even when running as CGI, the Apache process shouldn't exit until any child PHP processes are also killed. In effect, this script is killing itself halfway through.

Answer (score 1):

if a file containing only the start command works, then i suggest you to type this

```
    sleep 10
```

within the two commands (or more than 10 ! just check how long stopping takes and then adjust it) in order to make the batch wait 10 seconds.
Let me know, i'm curious.

Answer (score 0):

Change the file to

```
net stop apache2
net start apache2
```

Comment: If the PHP is called through Apache, than it may be that the script is killed befort it can restart Apache. It should work though, if you call it from te commandline: `PHP.exe yourscript.php`

Comment: @deizel work, but when apache is live, it do not work. in DOS also.

Comment: I think you need to wait until Apache stops before issuing the second command.

Comment: I think `net stop` waits until the service is stopped.

Answer (score 0):

Try executing a separate batch file that executes the restart script.